# What is "%_" in perl?

Tags: perl

I've just been given a code snippet:

```
@list = grep { !$_{$_}++ } @list;
```

As an idiom for deduplication. It seems to work, but - there's no `%_` listed in `perlvar`.

I'd normally be writing the above by declaring `%seen` e.g.:

```
my %seen; my @list = grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @list;
```

But `%_` seems to work, although it seems to be global scope. Can anyone point me to a reference for it? (Or at least reassure me that doing the above isn't smashing something important!)

Comment: Here is some discussion on it: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11757

Comment: Intriguing. So may be as simple as a leftover of the `_` typeglob? I wonder if there's anything more recent that 15 years ago. (But I guess if it hasn't changed, there'd be no reason for it).

Comment: Not that you would need a `local %_;` in the first snippet for the same reason you have `my %seen;` in the second.

Comment: So with something like `perl -E '{local %_; say grep { !$_{$_}++ } qw/a b c c d d e f g/; say %_ } say %_ ' ` the `local` is avoiding "pollution" of the global scope ?

Comment: @G. Cito, The variable is still globally visible, but it's value will be restored on scope exit. (My earlier comment should read "*Note* that you would need...")

Comment: In the same twisted way and for the same twisted reasons, you could also use `%0`, `%1`, ..., `%42`, ... or `%%`, `%"`, `%}`, `%$`, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a hash. You can have a hash named `_` because `_` is a valid name for a variable. (I'm sure you are familiar with `$_` and `@_`.)

No Perl builtin currently sets it or reads `%_` implicitly, but punctuation variables such as `%_` are reserved.

> Perl variable names may also be a sequence of digits or a single punctuation or control character (with the literal control character form deprecated). These names are all reserved for special uses by Perl

---

Note that punctuation variables are also special in that they are "super globals". This means that unqualified `%_` refers to `%_` in the root package, not `%_` in the current package.

```
$ perl -E'
   %::x    = ( name => "%::x"    );
   %::_    = ( name => "%::_"    );
   %Foo::x = ( name => "%Foo::x" );
   %Foo::_ = ( name => "%Foo::_" );

   package Foo;

   say "%::x    = $::x{name}";
   say "%::_    = $::_{name}";
   say "%Foo::x = $Foo::x{name}";
   say "%Foo::_ = $Foo::_{name}";

   say "%x      = $x{name}";
   say "%_      = $_{name}";
'
%::x    = %::x
%::_    = %::_
%Foo::x = %Foo::x
%Foo::_ = %Foo::_
%x      = %Foo::x
%_      = %::_      <-- surprise!
```

This means that forgetting to use `local %_` (as you did) can have very far-reaching effects.