# Why does $main::_ refer to the lexical $_ when used inside a map or for loop?

Tags: perl, scope

*In the process of [golfing down a solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104849/2771), I stumbled across this seemingly weird behavior*

---

I would have thought that `$::_` or `$main::_` would refer to the global `$_`, not the loop-local `$_`:

- **`$::_`**

  ```
  $ perl -E '$_=0; say $::_; say $::_ for 1..4'
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```
- **`$main::_`**

  ```
  $ perl -E '$_=0; say $main::_; say $main::_ for 1..4'
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```

---

Under **`-MO::Deparse`**, the results for both forms are identical:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -E '$_=0; say $::_; say $main::_ for 1..4'
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
$_ = 0;
say $_;
say $_ foreach (1 .. 4);
-e syntax OK
```

---

#### Update

It looks like explicitly declaring the `$_` loop variable with a `my` allows `$main::_` to work as expected:

```
$ perl -E '$_=0; for my $_ (1..4) { say $::_ }'
0
0
0
0
```

And `-MO=Deparse` happily obliges:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -E '$_=0; for my $_ (1..4) { say $::_ }'
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
$_ = 0;
foreach my $_ (1 .. 4) {
    say $main::_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Note that this is under Perl 5.16.3, so the [deprecation of `my $_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5240delta.html#Lexical-%24_-has-been-removed) doesn't apply.

***Questions***

- Is this behavior to be expected?
- Is this behavior any different in Perl 5.24?
- How do I access the value of `$_` declared outside the loop from within the loop (so `0`s are printed by the loop)?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think it's localized and thus you can't easily. But I am on my phone and can't try anything right now.

Comment: @Sobrique as mentioned, I was exploring possible ways to golf down an existing solution when I stumbled across this behavior. I just want to understand why `$main::_` gives the locally-scoped `$_` rather than the global one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846792/what-is-in-perl may be relevant.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I was trying to use it like so (under the `-n` flag): `say 1+grep{$::_>>=1}1..32`

Comment: @zdim I see it works when the local `$_` is explicitly declared with a `my`: `$_=0; for my $_ (1..4) { say $::_ }`

Comment: Yes, tried playing with that ... this is puzzling :))

Comment: More and more interesting ... `@main::_`  queried in a sub is the same as `@_` in that sub.   `perl -wE' sub f { say "@main::_ (@_)" }; say @_; f(1,2); say @_'`

Comment: There is no lexical `$_` in your code. Only `my` creates lexical variables.

Comment: @melpomene I don't know if it is significant to distinguish between local and lexical scope, but I hope the example makes my intended behavior clear

Comment: By "local", do you mean actual local scope (which is the same as "lexical") or what the `local` keyword does in Perl (which is what's happening here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is this behavior to be expected?*

Yes. You told the loop to use `$_` aka `$main::_`<sup>[1]</sup> as the loop variable, so it did.

If you want it to use a different variable, it's up to you to specify a different one.

> *Is this behavior any different in Perl 5.24?*

No.

> *I want it to access the value of $_ declared outside the loop from within the loop (so print 0's inside the loop)*

Use a different variable for your loop variable, make a copy of `$_` before the loop, take a reference to `$_` before the loop, or navigate the stack to find the directive that restores `$_`.

---

1. As documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), an unqualified reference to `$_` refers to `$main::_`, not `$_` in the current package.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is expected. Your one liner is equivalent to this:

```
$_ = 0;
say $_;
{
    local $_;
    $_ = 1;
    while( $_ <= 4 ){
        say $_;
    }continue{
        $_++;
    }
}
```

Perl localizes `$_` in `for`, `map`, and `grep` so that they don't clobber the value already in it. It does the same for `$a` and `$b` in `sort`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I want it to access the value of `$_` declared outside the loop from within the loop (so print 0's *inside* the loop)

Comment: This does answer the question. The `$_` in `for (1..4) {...}` is a localized `$main::_`, and you cannot access the original `$main::_` any more than you can in any other place where `local` hides a variables original value, e.g. `$foo::bar=42; for $foo::bar (1..6) { print $foo::bar #can't have the value 42 until this loop has ended }`

Comment: @mob what about Scope::Upper or similar? That might work.

Comment: Never heard of them. If you can come up with an answer for this question by using them, I'd love to see it and be enlightened.

Comment: You can't access it directly. The best you can do is use a `my` variable for the loop.

Comment: @mob I will try tomorrow. Was on my phone the whole day.