# <?php echo $_POST["name"] ; ?> Why we need Square Bracket here?

Tags: php, syntax

Is there any explanation why this " %_ " and "Square Bracket" is used ? 
i cant proceed without knowing this,
Thanks in advance .

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array. As per language design, you access the elements of such an array with the square bracket syntax: `$_POST["key"]`.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: *"Is there any explanation why this " %_ ""* - %_ is perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846792/what-is-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

**`$_` variables**

Built-in variables that begin with `$_` are so-called [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

> Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all scopes

**`[]` syntax**

[`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). As per the language design, accessing elements of such an array is performed via the square bracket notation:

```
echo $_POST["key"];
```

Comment: OP: *"Is there any explanation why this " %_ ""* - and not `$_` unless that was a typo on their part; to which the duplicates cover all these.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd assume it was a typo, seeing how the title refers to `$_POST`. But yeah, question is a duplicate anyway, what am I even doing here. :)

Comment: Either way; they did not do any research on this question.

Answer (score 0):

My explanation is: $_ and Square Bracket are part of the syntax. Every language has syntax = rule of writing.  Authors of a programming language are authors of the syntax.